# Spark: unable to create new native thread only happened on worker nodes

Tags: apache-spark, out-of-memory

there are 3 nodes, one is both master and worker and the other 2 are pure workers.

Standalone cluster. Hardwares are the same for the 3 boxes.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening when run spark worker with service command, i.e. service spark-worker start.

If start spark worker directly, i.e., sparkfolder/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://masterip:7077, the issue never happen.

Any suggestion?

Here is the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Spark Worker
After=network.target
OnFailure=plab-service-alarm@.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/sparkassandra/spark/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://the_master_IP:7077
ExecStop=/opt/sparkassandra/spark/sbin/stop-slave.sh
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitAS=infinity
CPUAccounting=true
CPUShares=100
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```